# How to load an external property file in Hadoop

Tags: spring, hadoop, configuration-files

I have a hadoop job which includes some spring beans.  Also, in the spring context file, there is a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer named app.properties.

This app.properties is within the jar file, the idea is remove it from the jar file in order to change some properties without re compile.

I tried the `-file` option, the `-jarlibs` option but neither worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was:

- Subclass the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
- Override loadProperties method
- If there is a custom System.getProperty("hdfs_path")

  ```
      try {
          Path pt = new Path(hdfsLocationPath);
          FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
          props.load(br);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          LOG.error(e);
      }
  ```

works like a charm ...

Answer (score 1):

You can add this properties file to the distributed cache as follows :

```
...
String s3PropertiesFilePath = args[0];
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(s3PropertiesFilePath), conf);
...
```

Later, in configure() of your mapper/reducer, you can do the following:

```
...
Path s3PropertiesFilePath;
Properties prop = new Properties();
@Override
public void configure(JobConf job) {
    s3PropertiesFilePath = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[0];
    //load the properties file
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(s3PropertiesFilePath.toString()));
...
}
```

**PS:** If you are not running it on Amazon EMR, then you can keep this properties file in your hdfs and provide that path instead.

Comment: That's good but I needed to replace the app.properties origin. With this approach, I still need to create a custom PropertyPlaceHolder to switch between both app.properties (external | internal). Thanks so much anyway.